# C# - group list by TimeSpan starting from specific start point

Tags: c#, linq, list, grouping, timespan

I want to group my list by time step (hour, day, week etc.) and count sum for each group but starting from specific time.

Now I've got input list:

```
TIME    VALUE
11:30   2
11:50   2
12:00   6
12:30   10
12:50   2
```

and hour step

```
var timeStep=new TimeSpan(1,0,0);
```

and I'm grouping my list with something like this

```
var myList = list.GroupBy(x =>
            {
                return x.Time.Ticks / timeStep.Ticks;
            })
            .Select(g => new { Time = new DateTime(g.Key * timeStep.Ticks), Value = g.Sum(x => x.Value) }).ToList();
```

It works fine (also for any other step, e.g. daily, weekly) and gives result:

```
TIME    SUM
11:00   4
12:00   18
```

But now I have to group my list with hour step but starting from e.g. 30 minute of hour, so what can I do to have something like this:

```
TIME    SUM
11:30   10
12:30   12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is preferable to use a custom DateTme comparer:

```
internal class DateTimeComparer : IEqualityComparer<DateTime>
{
    public bool Equals(DateTime x, DateTime y)
    {
        return GetHashCode(x) == GetHashCode(y);  
        // In general, this shouldn't be written (because GetHashCode(x) can equal GetHashCode(y) even if x != y (with the given  comparer)). 
        // But here, we have: x == y <=> GetHashCode(x) == GetHashCode(y)
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DateTime obj)
    {
        return (int)((obj - new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0)).Ticks / new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0).Ticks);
    }
}
```

with:

```
var myList = list.GroupBy(x => x.Time, new DateTimeComparer())
                 .Select(g => new { Time = g.Key, Value = g.Sum(x => x.Value) }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, it works :) What if I want to group list by month, but also with a specific start day (e.g. every 10th of month, so I will have sum of values from 10th of January to 10th of February etc)?

BTW, doesn't this DateTimeComparer work N * N times? Is it efficient?

Comment: No, the DateTimeComparer does not work N * N times. This is the power of the group by method. The items are stored in a kind of Dictionary with the _GetHashCode_ as key.